# define a list of id's for grouped item

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfoutput

i got a little question, i just can't understand, what is the problem and how do i solve it, i have a coldfusion variable, for example `#account_code#`, first of all, this code looks like this: `100.001.001` (there are bunch of them of cource) and i have some values for this variable, like `sum(nettotal)` and the cfquery i grouped by this `#account_code#`, all i want is to set the list of these codes, thus i define list, for example `<cfset code_list='100.001.001,100.001.002'>` and in query: `account_code in (#code_list#)` i also tried this one `account_code in ('#code_list#')` but instead it gives out the error, it says the Incorrect syntax near '.001'. as far as i understand i need to replace somehow these dots, and define the codes id's without them. thank you all for the help! i really appretiate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question is really how do you correctly use the SQL IN clause.

The SQL IN clause takes a list of values, if those values are numeric they do not need to be quoted, but your codes are strings, so each value needs to be quoted

```
select * from tbl
where id in ('100.001.001','100.001.002')
```

In ColdFusion the correct way to do this is the use <cfqueryparam> with list=true

```
<cfset code_list='100.001.001,100.001.002'>
<cfquery name="qSomething" ...>
select * from tbl
where id in (
  <cfqueryparam list="true" 
    value="#code_list#"
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
)
</cfquery>
```

This turns your list into multiple parameters in your query, and if your code_list is actually being passed in by a form or url variable helps to protect you from SQL injection attacks.